# How to get reference data from db in spring mvc application using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring mvc application using hibernate. We have created some entities like location, contact etc., and their respective controllers and daos. Following is my dispatcher servlet part:

```
<bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/MySqlDS" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bizmerlin.scm"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="contactService" class="com.bizmerlin.scm.services.ContactService"/>
    <bean id="contactDao" class="com.bizmerlin.scm.dao.ContactDao"/>
```

We are using hibernate for CRUD. Following is the hibernate code:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ContactModel.class);
            criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("contactName"));
            return criteria.list();
```

But on contact details page, I need to show countries drop down. I have put country list in db. How can we get country list without creating country model, dao, controller etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use country as an entity and map it into other entity beans, then you'll have to create model (if by "model" you mean entity bean). To access it you'll need a DAO method. To display it on a page, you'll need a controller method.

So, I guess there is no way around it. If you just need, for example, country name as String that you would use in other entities, then you could do it without creating entity, but you would still need DAO and controller methods.

Depends on your project, but you don't need to create separate DAO and controller **classes**. You only need new methods for countries, you can put them in some already existing classes.

If you only need country names, then you need something like this in your DAO class:

```
public List<String> findCountryNames() {
    return session.createSQLQuery("select name from country").list();
}
```

and a controller method which will return these results.

Comment: I need to use only country names in contact entity. How can I do this?